# local file is out of sync. Run 'scm load' with --force option to reload with workspace

Tags: git, rational-team-concert, ibm-jazz

I am facing the below issue while migrating the code from RTC to Git:

> Error: Problem running 'accept':
>   Local file system is out of sync. Run 'scm load' with --force option to reload the workspace.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Please share some code to see why this does not work.

Comment: Thanks for the update!

Comment: Since here the code is nothing but the code files (Java & .Net) and here it seems the problem with work space in rtc........ kindly needful...